# Boost Intrusive unordered_set incremental rehash

Tags: c++, boost, hashmap

How can I use the `boost::unordered_set<>::incremental_rehash()` API?

There is also `split_count()` that is related to the incremental rehashing. I already have `power_2_buckets<true>` option set for the hash map for faster binary-and rollover calculation.

Currently I do load balancing of the hash map via following code:

```
if(map.size() > buckets.size() * 0.97f) {
    // rehash
    std::vector<map_bucket> nbuckets(buckets.size()*2);

    map.rehash(map_bucket_traits(nbuckets.data(), nbuckets.size()));

    buckets = std::move(nbuckets);
}
```

As you can see I simply keep the bucket array in std::vector<> and construct new vector<> for each rehash.

I want to test out the incremental rehashing option but unfortunately I don't understand how to properly use it. And the small bit of boost.org documentation is confusing in this case. The incremental option is supposed to spread the cost of rehashing over many insertions/deletions overtime instead of occurring all at once.